# Angular 5 i18n: parsing templates with ng-xi18n and compiler-cli

Tags: angular, webpack, internationalization, angular-cli

I am adding translations to my Angular 5 app. The app does not use AOT compilation. Instead the translations are provided by the JIT compiler at bootstrap time as [indicated by the docs](https://angular.io/guide/i18n#merge-with-the-jit-compiler)

I have added the `i18n` tags in all my templates like so:

```
<span i18n="@@thanks">Thank you!</span>
```

Now I am wondering how to parse all the templates and build a `mesages.xlf` file. The documentation [gives instructions](https://angular.io/guide/i18n#create-a-translation-source-file-with-ng-xi18n) for how to do this with the Angular CLI but I am using webpack. One alternative presented is to use webpack's `AngularCompilerPlugin`, but that seems to be for AOT projects only. I've also tried the `ExtractI18nPlugin` (also part of `@ngtools/webpack`) but that also demands AOT.

The other alternative from the docs states:

> You can use the ng-xi18n tool directly from the @angular/compiler-cli
>   package. For more information, see [i18n in the CLI
>   documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/xi18n)

But the link leads back to Angular CLI instructions so I'm not sure what to do.  Basically, I have these templates with `i18n` tags that I want to turn into a `messages.xlf` without compiling the app.  Any leads?

Comment: Not sure if  you found this, or if it will help: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-internationalization

Comment: @R.Richards thanks for the link. Yes I've seen that page; it gives instructions for using the Angular CLI, but that isn't the tool I use to build my app.

Comment: An idea: install the CLI, build a side project with it, [ng eject](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/eject) the project, then you can look at the webpack config to see what they are doing behind the scenes. Maybe something there that would be useful.